# System.ComponentModel.IComponent ref. missing in MVC project. How to add it back?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to remove the unused reference from VS 2012- MVC 4.0 project. 
by mistakenly I have deleted all the references...

I am trying to add it back again, I have also added all ref. back , but one of ref. is still missing, I am unable to find it in Reference Manager, not in Assemble neither in COM section.

The error is ...

> The type 'System.ComponentModel.IComponent' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Answer (score 3):

I am also getting the same error when building the MVC application solution. For this issue add 'System' dll to the solution References folder.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the reference to the "System.dll" got removed.Solution to the problem is very simple add the reference to "System.dll".The dll is normally available in the following location
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727" .Add the reference your problem will get solved .